# How can I do to create a docker using matplotlib?

Tags: python, docker, matplotlib

Hello I want to dockerize this code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
plt.plot(a, a)
plt.show()
```

In my dockerfile I put :

```
FROM python:3
ADD main.py /
RUN pip install matplotlib
RUN pip install numpy
CMD [ "python", "./main.py"]
```

I type in the terminal :

```
docker build .
```

And then :

```
docker run <container_id>
```

But without any effects (I mean I don't see anything instead of seeing the plot)

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Where exactly do you expect the plot to show up?

Comment: I expect to see a figure with the plot like if I run directly `python3 main.py`

Comment: To see any kind of plot you need ipython kernel. If you run your script in the terminal you won't see any plot either.